# JSON not working as expected on iOS

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I'm currently trying to parse this JSON

```
[{"id":"1","dish_name":"Pasta & ketchup","category":"main","rating":"5","rating_count":null,"author":"Me","ingredients":"Pasta\nKetchup\nWater","description":"Very good for students\nCheap too!","picture":null,"protein":"7","fat":"11","carbs":"12","calories":"244","developer_lock":"1"},{"id":"2","dish_name":"Pasta & Kødsovs","category":"main","rating":"5","rating_count":null,"author":"Me","ingredients":"Pasta\nKødsovs\nWater","description":"Very good for students\nCheap too!","picture":null,"protein":"7","fat":"11","carbs":"12","calories":"244","developer_lock":"1"}]
```

But it fails and crashes with this code

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
    NSError *error = NULL;

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
    recipes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"dish_name"]];
    [uit reloadData];
}
```

Do someone have any clue, why it crashes with error `-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8077240`
?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to do some runtime error checking in your code.  Make certain your "`json`" dictionary is not nil (which is what I suspect is going on) and if it is, print out the value of your "`error`" NSError.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@ %@",error,json);` returns NULL error and my JSON.

Comment: and it seems that dish_name is a string, not an array.

Comment: How do I solve this. There is 2 recipes in the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message beginning with `[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]` means that you have an NSArray (the root object of the JSON is an array - notice the opening and closing square brackets) and you're trying to treat it as a dictionary. All in all,

```
recipes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:[json objectForKey:@"dish_name"]];
```

should be

```
recipes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObject:[[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"dish_name"]];
```

Note that there are two objects in the array, so you might want to use `[json objectAtIndex:1]` as well.

**Edit:** if you have a dynamic number of recipes, you can do this:

```
recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
    [recipes addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"dish_name"]];
}
```

Comment: Having multiple "`objectAtIndex`" and "`objectForKey`" calls happening within one line of code seems very risky to me, too. If "`objectAtIndex`" unexpectedly returns something not a dictionary, the app will probably behave in a crashy way.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Right. What I see is the JSON OP has consists of an array (root element) which has two dictionaries inside. You can call `objectForKey:` on those. I also fixed the error with the array being initialized improperly.

Comment: Now it works .. yeah, but not as I want. As said in the other comment above, there is two recipes in the JSON. The ´recipes´ NSArray now only contain the first, but not the second recipe.

Comment: @RoboForm What prevents you from writing `recipes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"dish_name"], [[json objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"dish_name"], nil];`?

Comment: The JSON is dynamic. It might return 1 recipe, but also up to 25 recipes. I therefore need some code parsing the JSON without knowing how many JSON recipes there is.

Comment: @RoboForm Then you can just add the recipe titles to a mutable array (see edit).

Comment: @RoboForm You're welcome, but please try to develop a bit of algorithmic thought - this question should not have been asked in fact, because it has a trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your `json` NSDictionary were a real & valid NSDictionary object, your call to this:

```
[json objectForKey:@"dish_name"]
```

should return exactly this:

```
"Pasta & ketchup"
```

Which is *definitely* not an array.  It's a NSString object.

Which would be why the call to "`initWithArray`" is bombing.

Comment: There is 2 recipes in the JSON. Should it still return `"Pasta & ketchup"`?

Comment: Michael Dautermann: no, this is not the problem. The root object is an array and not a dictionary.

Comment: That may be the case (and thanks for the -1 vote), but according to RoboForm's comment, his call to "`NSLog`" is printing out something for the "`json`" object.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I see - the JSON is itself valid, it's just that it's an array, not a dictionary. Let's see if what I answered resolves the problem (I suspect so).

Comment: @Mat I downvoted because the problem is not only here, but also before even the code flow could reach this point. OP has an array but treats it as a dictionary - and that should be fixed as well.

Comment: Ok, but i think that you could downvote a wrong answer, not a partial right answer. This is just my point of view.

Comment: Not the whole problem, but it solves the second "big" problem. And he clearly say "If your json were a real NSDictionary...".